# Modifying the current list item in a workflow

Tags: workflow, security

I have a workflow running when an item is adding to a document library. In this workflow, I have a code activity that I am attempting to set permissions to the list item. I am trying to break inheritance, and set some specific permissions. I've done this before so I'm not concerned with the code for this.

The issue that I am running in to is when checking the item back in to SharePoint. When I run checkin, I get the generic error saying `The security validation for this page is invalid`. There is no exception thrown in the code and I can step over it without issue. However, after this code block, the error is in the logs and the workflow says `Failed to start (retrying)`. This workflow has worked numerous times prior to me adding this code activity.

Here is the code block I am working with (simplified, but non-functioning):

```
workflowProperties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPListItem item = workflowProperties.Item;
item.File.CheckOut();
item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
item.SystemUpdate(false);
item.File.CheckIn("permissions updated");
workflowProperties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Any ideas? I've tried running an `UndoCheckout()` on the File, but the same result occurs.

**Edit 1**

The reason I was performing the checkout is that I found my workflow would end up with 'Failed on start (retrying)' after the item permissions have been set. The logs say

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The security validation for this
>   page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and
>   try your operation again. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8102006D): The security
>   validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser,
>   refresh the page, and try your operation

**Edit 2**

Ok, I can break role inheritance fine without checking in/out. The reason I had all of that in there was because I am attempting to assign new permissions, which I think requires the update. I had stripped that out when posting. This is a records library, and items are immediately declared records. That's the need for the check in/out.

**Edit 3**

I ended up moving this to an event receiver. Worked as expected.

Comment: I have played with this code in console application. Is there any special reason you are using check in/out? If you are only breaking permissions inheritance simple ´item.BreakRoleInheritance(false)´ will do. ´SystemUpdate()´ is also not needed. You also need to check if your file is not already checked out (it will throw exception if you call ´CheckOut()´ if file is already 'out'). Disclaimer: Since I am not too good at workflows and I tested this only in console app maybe I am not helping here :)

Comment: Can you try incorporating the SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()  or workflowProperties.Web.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = False in your code?

Comment: See my edits...

Comment: Deepu, FormDigestSettings are on the SPWebApplication, not SPWeb. I get an access denied trying that.

Comment: I've had the same problem, workflow already assumes the RunWithElevatedPrivledges so don't set the AllowUnsafeUpdates back to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest running your code in ItemAdded event instead of an activity in a workflow. Also I don’t think BreakRoleInheritance requires you checkout the file, you may want to remove unwanted code.

Comment: This needs to be done in the workflow.
See my update in the OP

Comment: This is now an option. Exploring this idea as it seems a permission thing is better suited outside of the workflow

Answer (score 1):

If you have a need to update/modify a list item within a Workflow activity, you should only access that list item using the workflow item service, rather than accessing via the standard SharePoint `SPList` object.

I was reading all about this just the other day in the excellent [Inside SharePoint 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627460) book.

Pages 422 & 423 have the following to say about accessing tasks, site content and list items from custom code in a workflow activity context:

> Note that the Execute method of an activity is always called by the WF
>   runtime; it should  never be called directly by developers. When the
>   WF runtime calls the  Execute method, it  passes an
>   ActivityExecutionContext  parameter , which makes it possible to
>   access workflow  services. SharePoint Foundation extends WF with
>   several SharePoint-specific workflow services,  including the
>   SharePoint Service, the Task Service, and the List Item Service, all
>   of which can  be accessed using the following code.
>
> ```
> protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext context) {  
>
>   ISharePointService SPService =   
>           (ISharePointService)context.GetService(typeof(ISharePointService)); 
>   ITaskService TaskService =  
>           (ITaskService)context.GetService(typeof(ITaskService)); 
>   IListItemService ListItemService =  
>           (IListItemService)context.GetService(typeof(IListItemService));  
>
>   // Now perform work using workflow services 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that while your code is executing in the context of a workflow
>   instance, you must create  tasks and update site content using
>   workflow services. For example, you should not create  tasks and
>   update list items using standard server-side object model techniques.
>   Instead, you  must create tasks using the Task Service and update
>   items using the List Item Service. Here  is a sample implementation of
>   the Execute method that uses the SharePoint Service to log a  comment
>   to the workflow history list.
>
> ```
> protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext context) {  
>   // get reference to SharePoint Service 
>   ISharePointService SPService =   
>           (ISharePointService)context.GetService(typeof(ISharePointService)); 
>
>   // use SharePoint Service to perform work  
>   SPService.LogToHistoryList( 
>     this.WorkflowInstanceId,  
>     SPWorkflowHistoryEventType.WorkflowComment, 
>     this.UserId,  
>     TimeSpan.MinValue, 
>     "The 'Hello World' activity",  
>     "My description",  
>     "My custom data"); 
>
>     // return Closed to indicate the activity has completed 
>     return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed; 
>   }  
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and lengthy post, but I am not in a custom workflow activity. This is a visual studio custom workflow so I don't have a `Context` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `currentweb.allowunsafeupdate = true` and currentsite.all`enter code here`owunsafeupdates = true.
Your error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, workflow already assumes the `RunWithElevatedPrivledges` so don't set the `AllowUnsafeUpdates` back to false.